# ClamAV Bytecode run timed out

Tags: antivirus

I have the following output by ClamAV:

```
Starting a daily scan of /root directory.
Amount of data to be scanned is 205M.
Starting a daily scan of /var/www directory.
Amount of data to be scanned is 121G.
LibClamAV Warning: [Bytecode JIT]: Bytecode run timed out, timeout flag set
LibClamAV Warning: [Bytecode JIT]: recovered from error
LibClamAV Warning: [Bytecode JIT]: JITed code intercepted runtime error!
LibClamAV Warning: Bytecode 79 failed to run: CL_ETIMEOUT: Time limit reached
```

What are these warnings? What do they mean? How can I fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Searching for these messages quickly leads to posts like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193059/warnings-errors-when-running-clamav-clamscan-scanning-3tb-hard-drive). Basically: you are scanning huge data and it runs in a timeout while scanning since there was a timeout configured. If you want to extend the timeout you can do on the command line as documented.